# List of compiled functions and then plot them 1 by 1.

Tags: compile

I would like to create a list of compiled functions and then plot them 1 by 1. 
To illustrate the problem (In reality the functions I want to compile are of course not x^j but some complicated matrices):

```
cf = Table[Compile[{{x, _Real}}, x^j], {j, 1, 3}]
```

as output I get a list of compiled functions.
Then I would like to plot one of them, for example the second:

```
Plot[cf[[2]][x], {x, -1, 1}]

During evaluation of In[107]:= CompiledFunction::cfse: Compiled expression j should be a machine-size integer. >>

During evaluation of In[107]:= CompiledFunction::cfex: Could not complete external evaluation at instruction 1; proceeding with uncompiled evaluation. >>
```

This is a bit weird since if I compile all those functions independently (without the use of a table around Compile) I can plot them nicely.

I hope this is not just a stupid syntax error, I am quite new to mathematica so please excuse me my probably stupid question :)

Luke

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use `Evaluate` inside the `Compile` call,

```
cf = Table[
  Compile[{{x, _Real}}, Evaluate[x^j]], {j, 1, 3}]

Plot[cf[[2]][x], {x, -1, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: @march Interesting, I get the same error as OP

Comment: Nevermind. Didn't remove your `Evaluate` after copying and pasting. But `Table[With[{j = j}, Compile[{{x, _Real}}, x^j]], {j, 1, 3}]` still works.

Comment: @march, that's what I would've gone with, too; `With[]` is handy for injecting externally-produced stuff into a compiled function.

Comment: @J.M. I agree that `With` is great, but the fact is that I use `Evaluate`  **every single** time I use `Compile`.  I can't think of a situation where I wouldn't do do it. If it were bash I would make an alias